# Ext validation for datefield against copy/paste of characters

Tags: extjs

In datefield, I am using regular expression(maskRe) to prevent user from entering alphabets, but If the user try to copy paste the same, he can get his alphabetical text on my datefield, so is there any way to solve  this particular issue. I dont want cop/paste to be disabled.
I am using EXT 4.2 version...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide us with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find these example . It will solves your issue without disabling Copy/Paste

```
 Ext.onReady(function(){

                    test = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date', {
                    width: 320,
                    enableKeyEvents:true,
                    listeners:{
                        keyup:function( thiss, e, eOpts  ){
                             var str=thiss.value;
                             if(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str)){
                             alert("Contains alphabets");
                             thiss.reset();
                             }

                            }
                        },
                    value:'10.69',
                    renderTo:document.body

                    });
         });
```

Comment: thanks, will try it...hi, is there a function like autoCreate in ext 4.2 version for this type of validations?